# What is the difference between guest and auth middleware in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-middleware

//kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
];
```

what should i use, auth or guest middleware for authentication ? what is the difference between auth and guest middleware?

Comment: You should use laravel's own authentication system not middleware. You may use middleware to give access to users. See https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#authentication-quickstart

Answer (score 3):

**Auth Middleware**

Determine if the user is logged in to any of the guards.If not logged in then it will throw `AuthenticationException` and redirecting to login page.

**Guest Middleware**

Here it will check if user is logged in to any of the guards.If so it redirect to `RouteServiceProvider::HOME` mentioned page . or else it passes to requested page.

If you want to protect you routes from non login user then use `auth middleware`

Answer (score 3):

**auth middleware** - It is for session authentication. auth middleware check whether user is authenticated or not. if there is no session for a user then this route will redirect the request to login route.

```
    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('login');
        }
    }
```

**guest middleware** - This middleware logic is that if user is logged in, redirect them to `RouteServiceProvider::HOME`.

```
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {
        $guards = empty($guards) ? [null] : $guards;

        foreach ($guards as $guard) {
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

you can set the `RouteServiceProvider::HOME` path in `App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider`